# Why PRINT won't produce the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure to solve problem 2 of project Euler and the print statement will not print the results. I have tried using select but it also does not work. I have put print statements everywhere to see if any of them run.  I have tested this code in Visual studio (in C# form of course) and it runs so I don't think it is the code any ideas?

```sql
USE [johnsodx]
GO
  /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[kibonacci]    Script Date: 11/10/2020 10:16:46 AM ******/
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  -- =============================================
  -- Author:        <Author,,Name>
  -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
  -- Description:   <Description,,>
  -- =============================================
Create PROCEDURE Fibonacciss

AS

DECLARE @f0 INT
DECLARE @f1 INT
DECLARE @fcom INT
DECLARE @f_sum INT

SET  @f0 = 1
SET  @f1 = 1
SET  @fcom = 0
SET  @f_sum = 0

 set statistics time on --Keeps track of the time it takes to excute query
 Print @f_sum
 while @fcom <= 4000000 
 BEGIN
 set @fcom = @f0 + @f1;

  if (@fcom % 2 = 0)
  set
      @f_sum += @fcom;


   set  @f0 = @f1;
   set   @f1 = @fcom;

   Print @f_sum
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.


-- Insert statements for procedure here
   Print @f_sum
   Print @fcom
   END
    Print  @f_sum
```

Comment: It appears that your screen capture (which is highly discouraged for providing information) contains the result of your creation script. You did not execute the procedure after creating it.

Comment: And do actually implement what that comment in the middle says! Add "set nocount on;" as the first statement in your procedure.

Comment: @SMor I removed the picture. Also, I removed the set noncount on to see if it would do anything. Could you expand on what you meant though, saying I didn't execute it?

Comment: Removing the picture but not adding any context in your question does not help. But your picture appeared to be the screen shot of the query window where you executed the script you posted. That is, the script where you CREATED the procedure. You did not show the output of the query where you EXECUTED the procedure (as far as I can tell - you cut off the query portion). For nocount [read this](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/finding-code-smells-using-sql-prompt-set-nocount-problem-pe008-pe009)

Comment: I took your code and created [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c45b952f2332a58ae45191c15e015e4a) to demonstrate that, when executed, does produce output. And really - you should be able to debug like this. I adjusted the upper bound to avoid millions of printed values. Maybe you are impatient?

Comment: @SMor your right, it works on yours but for mine, it won't print the results. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb and didn’t know the difference between execution: creating and running it